# How does Personal File Sharing work?

Tags: 12.04, samba, file-sharing, macosx

I'm currently using Samba to share files between my ubuntu PC and my mac. However, I notice that there is a 'Personal File Sharing' preference panel built into ubuntu. Is it possible to view my ubuntu Public folder from my mac using just what comes pre-installed on ubuntu, since every guide/tutorial/post I've found so far just tells me to use Samba?

Answer (score 2):

The files that you will have to install are:

```
apache2.2-bin
Apache HTTP Server common binary files

The Apache Software Foundation’s goal is to build a secure, efficient and
extensible HTTP server as standards-compliant open source software. The
result has long been the number one web server on the Internet.

libapache2-mod-dnssd
Zeroconf support for Apache 2 via avahi

mod_dnssd is an Apache HTTPD module which adds Zeroconf support
via DNS-SD using Avahi. This allows Apache to advertise itself and the
websites available to clients compatible with the protocol.
```

Install both from the synaptic package manager, and reboot after you have installed. Once you have rebooted the computer, you will be able to enable the personal file sharing for Ubuntu 10.04

that will solve your problem in order to use it. The libapache2-mod-dnssd you don't need its already installed via avahi which is on your system. logout and back in.